# Generate war file for some GWT's modules only

Tags: gwt, module, war, entry-point

I have a GWT application that have around 10 modules (.gwt.xml), of course each module has their own entry point. Some of my modules are:

1. Login
2. Costs
3. Sale
4. Shops

etc.

What I need to do is generate a war file of two modules, for example. Login and Sale. So, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate war file for two module only so you just need to compile two module only.

In GWT Compile project options ->  Entry point module -> shows all four entry points

There is a button "Remove" which will use for ignore other entry point in compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on which build tool you are using. If you are using maven build tool you can comment the modules(I mean **module** tags) which are you do not want to compile in the gwt-maven plugin.

I have not used ant build tool. If you are using ant try passing the different values for **gwt.module.name** argument.

If you are not using build tool that depends on your IDE options.

Please tell us in which way you are compiling your gwt modules. So that we can provide the exact solution.

Comment: I'm using Maven for compiling.

Comment: Are you able to exclude few modules while compile? Still if you see the problem please paste the gwt plugin configuration in the pom.xml.